# How can I strip a matching pattern by using a for-loop in python 2.7?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, loops, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am in the proces of making a dictionary of an OCR'd txt.file. At this point, I am trying to make a 'clean' slugline so that I - later - can easily identify specific parts of information I want to put in my dictionary. But that is context. Point is that I am new to python.

I have a problem in deleteting al the spaces and komma's in the slugline, because I dont know how to use lookbehinds to identify the right matching pattern, and strip this specific pattern.

---

This is an excerpt of the txt.file, read as lines:

```
[AANVRAAGNUMMER:__542-13___AANVRAGER:  Dr.B.Leijnse en Dr.H.M. van Praag, ___LOCATIE:_Rotterdam___ONDERZOEKSONDERWERP:   bestudering van het werkingsmechanisme van de anti-depressieve hydrazinen, in bio chemisch en psychiatrisch-psychologisch opzicht  __BEDRAG:__ f 16.000]
[AANVRAAGNUMMER:__547-7___AANVRAGER:  Dr.H.K.A. Visser, ___LOCATIE:_Groningen___ONDERZOEKSONDERWERP:   onderzoek over de werking van het antidiuretische hormoon en de regulatie van de centrale afgifte van dit hormoon gedurende de kinderleeftijd (1962)  __BEDRAG:__ f 9.600]
[AANVRAAGNUMMER:__548-4___AANVRAGER:  Dr.F.Schwarz, ___LOCATIE:_Utrecht___ONDERZOEKSONDERWERP:   onderzoek naar de invloed van Exophthalmos Producing Substance op bindweefsel  __BEDRAG:__ f 13.000] 
[AANVRAAGNUMMER:__562-8___AANVRAGER:  Prof. Dr.J.Droogleever Fortuyn, ___LOCATIE:_Groningen___ONDERZOEKSONDERWERP:   onderzoek naar bouw en functie van de middenhersenen (1960-1962___AANVRAGER: ) __BEDRAG:__ f 13.100]
```

In the end I want it to look like this (to take the example of the first line):

```
[AANVRAAGNUMMER:__542-13___AANVRAGER:Dr.B.Leijnse en Dr.H.M. van Praag___LOCATIE:_Rotterdam___ONDERZOEKSONDERWERP:bestudering van het werkingsmechanisme van de anti-depressieve hydrazinen, in bio chemisch en psychiatrisch-psychologisch opzicht__BEDRAG:__f 16.000]
```

---

The following code is an example of how I tried to strip the the pattern between "AANVRAGER:" and "___LOCATIE". So have want to match group<1>, but I don't know how to apply that to for-loop. I guess that I can expand the compile regex, so I can accomplish the intended result.

```
#Import regular Expression Library
import re

#Import data
IN = open('OrderedPhase1.txt', 'r')
OUT = open ('StrippedCategories.txt', 'w')
LinesRAW = IN.readlines()

#create regular expression of which group<1> identifies the targeted text
aanvrager = re.compile(r"""(?<=AANVRAGER:)
                       ([\D]+)
                       (?=___LOCATIE)
                       """, re.VERBOSE)

#loop for identififying the matching pattern and strip delete comma's and spaces using the strip-method
for line in LinesRAW:
    if aanvrager.match(line):
        stripped = line.strip(',').strip()

        #write new lines to file
        OUT.write(stripped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex with `re.sub` and `\1\2\3` replacement pattern:

```
r'(AANVRAGER:)\W*(.*?)\W*(___LOCATIE)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OeQ4An/2).

**Details**

- `(AANVRAGER:)` - Group 1: a literal string
- `\W*` - 0 or more non-word chars
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\W*` - 0 or more non-word chars
- `(___LOCATIE)` - Group 3: a literal string.

In your code,

```
aanvrager = re.compile(r'(AANVRAGER:)\W*(.*?)\W*(___LOCATIE)')
for line in LinesRAW:
    OUT.write(aanvrager.sub(r'\1\2\3', line))
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't know it was possible that way! It works, and if I change the literal strings in for example ONDERZOEKSONDERWERP: and __BEDRAG. It works in that case as well.

Comment: @MartijnvanderMeer `r'\n'` is not a newline, it is a combination of 2 chars, ``\`` and `n`. You need ``FinalRegex.sub('\n\\1\\2\n\\3', line)``

Comment: Yes! I figured it out.. Should have tried a bit better before asking - sorry!